# How to close a Visual basic console application?

Tags: vb.net, console-application

I wanted to know if there is 1 line of code I can enter that terminates the console application when executed. I've tried Environment.exit(0) and that didn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Here is the code i have so far:

```
Sub Exit_Program()
    Console.Clear()

    Console.WriteLine("************************************************")
    Console.WriteLine(" ")
    Console.WriteLine("Are you sure you want to exit? if so type 'exit' or type 'back' to get back to the main menu.")
    Console.WriteLine(" ")
    Console.WriteLine("************************************************")

    Dim Exit_confirm As String

    Exit_confirm_error:
    Try
        Exit_confirm = Console.ReadLine()
    Catch
        Console.WriteLine(" ")
        Console.WriteLine("     Error: Are you sure you want to exit? if so type 'exit' or type 'back' to get back to the main menu.")
        Console.WriteLine(" ")
        GoTo Exit_confirm_error
    End Try

    Select Case Exit_confirm
        Case "exit"
            ' code that terminates the console application (?)
        Case "back"
            Main()
        Case Else
            Console.WriteLine(" ")
            Console.WriteLine("     Error: Are you sure you want to exit? if so type 'exit' or type 'back' to get back to the main menu.")
            Console.WriteLine(" ")
            GoTo Exit_confirm_error
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Environment.Exit(0)

Comment: Code wont run if i do that ;( it wants me to have something in the brackets.

Comment: Like 0.  The `End` keyword is standard Basic.

Comment: FYI, that `Catch` block is absolutely useless.

Comment: And `GoTo` is considered pretty poor form these days.  You can easily rejigger your code to use a `Do` or `While` loop.

Comment: Having to type "exit" or "back" every time gets annoying after the first time. I suggest using "y" or "n" in a case-insensitive manner.

Comment: How would I do it using a while loop, any links to webpages I could use for help?

Comment: If you think that you are capable of writing software then I think it's fair that we assume that you're capable of finding information on how to write a loop for yourself. The thing to do is to pick up a pen and paper and first write down what the code actually has to do, then try to write code to do it. Trying to write code without knowing what it has to do is the main reason beginners find it so hard to write code.